# Why is custom dependency not in Referenced Libraries under Eclipse?

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.1

I have this as part of `Build.scala` (note the last line with `"com.github.thiagolocatelli" % "parse4j" % "1.3"`):

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  // Add your project dependencies here,
  javaCore,
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  "com.github.thiagolocatelli" % "parse4j" % "1.3"
)
```

Running `play compile` on command line gives:

> [info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.3.1!httpcore.jar

I find `parse4j.jar` in `...play-2.1.2\repository\cache\com.github.thiagolocatelli\parse4j\jars` but not in the project's `Referenced Libraries` inside Eclipse. I supposed I could copy and paste the jar manually but I'm curious why the dependency didn't work in `Build.scala`.

Comment: How did you import the project to Eclipse? I don't know if there's auto-import feature in Eclipse so every change in build configuration would require repeating the steps to import the project. Just guessing.

Comment: after converting my play project into an eclipse project using the "eclipse" command in the play console I selected File-->Import-->Existing Projects Into Workspace.  I did this way before adding the parse4j dependency in Build.scala though.

Comment: Just to make sure all's fine from sbt/play's point of view, go to sbt shell and do `show libraryDependencies`. If the library's listed there, Eclipse's the culprit (protip: time for IDEA :-))